# cron job never ends

Tags: cron

A few days ago, I started to get a large number of cron errors "Too late for the schedule". Now that I have time to investigate - I see that the task "newsletter_send_all" is never ending/always running. According to AOESchuduler, it started on 2015-09-11 22:30:03, but has never finished.

How can I fix that?

(PS. emails are still being sent by the shop... so thats not an issue).

Comment: Start by truncating your `cron_schedule` table in the database and let it rebuild a new schedule. Then check the logs for possible errors relating to one or more of the cronjobs

Comment: Thanks... that did the job (at least for now). Its running all clean again.

Comment: excellent! added my comment as answer if you would like to accept :) Cronjobs have hickups like that form time to time, still not sure why

Comment: tackling lots of issues at present, so really happy to have one fixed so quickly and easily :)

Comment: `for((i=0;i==0;i+=0)); do mpg123 lampchops.mp3; done`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by truncating your `cron_schedule` table in the database and let it rebuild a new schedule. Then check the logs for possible errors relating to one or more of the cronjobs.